# Convert GIF to MP4 on device

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, gif, mp4

Is it possible to take a remote (but I can download it first if needed) GIF sequence and make a MPMoviePlayerViewController playable mp4 on the device?

I have tried using http://api.online-convert.com/, but the API doesn't suit and the free version is too restricted for our needs.

[Imagemagick for iOS](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#iOS) also doesn't seem to include GIF support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This wasn't so easy. There is a gist snippet [here](https://gist.github.com/4104323) with the solution.

Comment: Hey Paul, two things: I checked out your implementation and its pretty cool! Thx for that. I have a tip for you and a question :D You should only do totalFrameDelay += delayTime.floatValue; if currentFrame!=0 to avoid black starting frame. My question: I found that for many GIFs the color table is broken after converting with your code. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Sorry no, I wrote this several years ago now and don't remember. Thanks for the bug fix!

Comment: I just found the problem. For some reason on the device (not in the simulator) iOS changes the RGB order to GBR, this only happens for some frame dimensions!

Comment: Swift 3 version?

Answer (score 5):

Swift 3.0 version.

https://gist.github.com/powhu/00acd9d34fa8d61d2ddf5652f19cafcf

Usage

```
let data = try! Data(contentsOf: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "gif", withExtension: "gif")!)
let tempUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath:NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent("temp.mp4")
GIF2MP4(data: data)?.convertAndExport(to: tempUrl, completion: { })
```

Comment: Note: the converter is only iOS >=11

Answer (score 0):

1st -  Separate all images from GIF . 
2nd -  Create video from that separate images.

Please check this one. i think you can solution which you want. 
With this Link you can easily convert GIF file to MP4. 
Click 
https://github.com/dennygajera/gifToMp4

Comment: “While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.”